# How to create a separate column of numbers using 3-character separator?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to separate a column of data in Excel, with the numbers following the " - " in a second column. The data looks like this:

```
Cabin-Fever - 28,315
CANBRICKYYJ - 11
Capstone - 170,049
CB Brick Builds  - 41
CCX-Custom-Works - 53
```

Using the formula "=--MID(A1,FIND(" - ",A1)+3,LEN(A1))" I can move the numbers to a second column (thank you, Scott!), but the original column retains the numbers. I would like to remove the dash and numbers from column A, and have only the numbers in column B. The end result would look like:

```
A                  B
Cabin-Fever        28,315
CANBRICKYYJ        11
Capstone           170,049
CB Brick Builds    41
CCX-Custom-Works   53
```

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot change the existing data in place with a formula.  You would need to put the output into two new columns.

Comment: That formula would be `=LEFT(A1,FIND(" - ",A1)-1)`

Comment: Thank you again, @ScottCraner ! This works perfectly. However, it looks like you added this as a comment, rather than as an answer. Can I post this as an "answer" and then close it off? Or would you like to do that? I want to ensure you get credit for the response.

Comment: You can also create a table out of the data and than have it delimited using power query, but that'll still populate the data next to the existing data. To really change the data (directly) you would need VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these formulas

trim is optional if there is empty spaces you want to remove.

=TRIM(LEFT(A2,FIND(" - ",A2)-1))

=TRIM(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" - ",A2)-1))

or

=LEFT(A2,FIND(" - ",A2)-1)

=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" - ",A2)-1)

[image: Here is the example]